# Incorporate react scheduler into my existing web application

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I am very new to React, so please bear with me. I have an existing web application created in Visual studio 2017. It's not MVC project. I have found this react calendar

https://github.com/hiramzamorano/react-big-scheduler

And I would like to use it with my project. But I am not sure how to reference the library. Firstly, this link tells me how to add React library to my page

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project

Now I am stuck when I keep reading the calendar documentation about running:

npm install scheduler-react --save

After running the command, literally there are hundreds of files being saved into node_module folder. How could I reference them all? A lot of tutorial online for React and Visual Studio is mostly related to MVC project. I could not find much information dealing with web application.

Comment: Anybody could help please? Even a link or some suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks